# How does coingecko api requests limit work? Getting too many requests error after second request

Tags: python, api, python-requests, rapidapi, coingecko

I am trying to get some data from coingecko. In the first request fetching list of 100 biggest currencies. In following requests I want to fetch some detailed info about the biggest currencies. Unfortunately already for the second request I am receiving the too many requests error. I am able to make another successful request after a few minutes but with this pace it would take hours to get info about all the big currencies.
I am using rapidapi.com that is recommended by coingecko website.

I used a copy of the code from documentation e.g.:

```
import requests

url = "https://coingecko.p.rapidapi.com/coins/%7Bid%7D"

querystring = {"localization":"true","tickers":"true","market_data":"true","community_data":"true","developer_data":"true","sparkline":"false"}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "coingecko.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "mykey"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The [CoinGecko](https://rapidapi.com/coingecko/api/coingecko/) API is completely free on RapidAPI and has a rate limit of 50 calls/minute.

It should be working fine now. Give it another go. I have tested this API on RapidAPI, and I'm getting the expected response.

Comment: Do you by chance know the monthly limit for this plan? Example, the analyst plan allows for 500k calls a month.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was just misled by rapidapi.com article. Actually it is better to go directly via coingecko api. You can find more info at https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation